# Which drawable folder for 480x800 and 1024x600 in android?

Tags: android, drawable

I am making an app which should be for multiple Tablet screen. I have already made something like ....

```
1. i have make a folder named : layout-sw600dp for 1024 x 600 resolution which takes image from drawable-large folder. 

2.  i have make a folder named : layout-sw720dp for 1280 x 800 resolution which takes image from drawable-xlarge folder.
```

now i want to make it in resolution 480x800 so my question is in which folder i should put my xml file and in in which folder i should put my images ?

Please help me ....thank you in advance........

Answer (score 2):

Put your all xml files in `layout-large` folder and put images in `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Comment: xml files should be in layout-large folder ?

Comment: yes . you have to put all the xml files in layout-large folder

Comment: and what about images ?where should i pur it ?

Comment: 400x800 -> layout. Tablet layouts go to layout-large folder.
Images for tablets (if splash, etc) -> drawable-large. Put icons in respective dpi folder, e.g. drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi

Comment: actually xml file successfull putted from layout folder but my question is where should i put images for resolution 480 x 800

Comment: 400x800 phones are hdpi, so as Chirag Raval said, drawable-hdpi

Comment: for 480 x 800 resolution i have putted xml fils in layout and image in drawable-hdpi folder but images come from drawable-large folder

Answer (score 0):

check this in

Device defination

1) first click on Android {virtual device manager} and there click on Device defination and check for resolution and dive folder names layout-hdpi and you get screen similar it on Eclipse